# CRUD: Edit function not working it changes nothing in the show all page

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to set up an edit method in PHP for CRUD but when I click the edit button to run the query it just takes me to the show all page and no changes are made their.

```php
    {<!doctype html>
    <?php include 'db.php';
    $id=$_GET['id'];
    $sql="select * from users where id='$id'";
    $rows=$db->query($sql);
    $row=$rows->fetch_assoc();
    if (isset($_GET['add'])){
        $name=$_GET['name'];
        $email=$_GET['email'];
        $pass=$_GET['pass'];
        $sql2="Update users set name='$name',email='$email',password='$pass' 
    where id=$id";
        $db->query($sql2);
        header('Location:show.php');
    }

    ?>
```

```html
    <head>
    <title>List</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 70px;">
        <h1 class="text-center">All Users List</h1>
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <table class="table">
                <hr><br>
                <form method="get" >
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <h1><?php echo $row['id'];?></h1>
                        <label>Name</label>
                        <input type="text" required name="name" value="<?php 
   echo $row['name'];?>" class="form-control">
                        <label>Email</label>
                        <input type="email" required name="email" value="<?php
    echo $row['email'];?>" class="form-control">
                        <label>Password</label>
                        <input type="password" required name="pass" value="<? 
    php echo $row['password'];?>" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" name="add" value="Edit" class="btn 
    btn-success">&nbsp;
                </form>
            </table>
            <button onclick="history.go(-1);" class="btn btn-primary">Back 
    </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

No changes are happening in all users table

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually building your queries like that. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: **Never store passwords in clear text!**. Only store password hashes! Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) . If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I _really_ hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) to get the same functionallity.

Comment: Also, update the user _before_ you select the data. Right now, you're first fetching the existing data from the database, then you update the database and after that, you output the existing data you fetched before the update. Just do: first update (if it's an update), _then_ fetch the user data. That way, you will get the updated data instead.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you may create a new function called goback() and called on click from the Back button.

```
function  goback(value){
  window.history.go(value);
 }

    <button onclick="goback(-1);" class="btn btn-primary">Back     </button>
```